# Не жалеешь(,) что так рано женился. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Не жалеешь что так рано женился
Нужна ли тут запятая перед "что"?

Comment: Это вообще утвердительное или вопросительное предложение у Вас?

Answer (score 1):

Не жалеешь, что так рано женился.

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, ЧТО - союз, запятая нужна.